# REGEXP in MYSQL isn't working for full word search all time

Tags: mysql, regex

I've a table like this,

```
values
-------------------
male,female
PHP 30
PHP (30)
PHP ($30),CSS ($20)
PHP {$30},CSS {$20}
PHP [$30],CSS [$20]
PHP (€30),CSS (20)
```

I've prepared the sql like this,

```
SELECT mytable.values FROM mytable WHERE mytable.values REGEXP '[[:<:]]PHP ($30)[[:>:]]'
```

It should match one row (4th), but it's not working.

It's also not working with
`() / {} / [] or any types of symbols like $ / €`

I want to mention here that,

1. `MYSQL LIKE` isn't the right thing for me I think, because it won't work if we want to match `male`.
2. `REGEXP` is working for `PHP 30` here and it's working for only strings.

Could anyone please inform me what will be the best solution to match the exact word or sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Escape special characters with a literal backslash. 2) There is no word boundary between `)` and whitespace. Do not use `[[:>:]]` in that case.

Comment: Could you please inform me what will be the correct sql for me with this line? `SELECT mytable.values FROM mytable WHERE mytable.values REGEXP '[[:<:]]PHP ($30)[[:>:]]'
`

Comment: `REGEXP '[[:<:]]PHP \\(\\$30\\)'`

Comment: My issue has been fixed. Thank you so much.